# Schur complement

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

I am trying to understand what steps need to be done to go from $P-A^TPA\succ0$ (with $P \succ 0$ and $G$ can be any matrix) to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
P & A^TG^T \\
GA& G + G^T - P 
\end{bmatrix} \succ 0$$

Trying to use the proof

$$T\begin{bmatrix}
P & A^TG^T \\
GA& G + G^T - P 
\end{bmatrix}T^T = P-A^TPA \succ0$$

with $T =  \begin{bmatrix}
I &
-A^T 
\end{bmatrix}$
I am only able to get $P-A^TGA-A^T(G-P)A^T$. If $ G = P$, then it should hold. Since $G$ can be any matrix, his can't hold, or am I wrong?

---

Edit:
I am reading the paper "A new discrete-time robust stability condition" by M.C. de Oliveira, J. Bernussou, J.C. Geromel.

A linear time-discrete system is given $x_{k+1} = A(\alpha) + B(\beta)u_k$, for which: $A(\alpha) \quad \in \quad\mathcal{X}_A := \{A(\alpha): A(\alpha) := \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \alpha_iA_i,\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \alpha_i = 1,  \alpha_i \geq 0\}$
$B(\beta) \quad \in \quad\mathcal{X}_B := \{B(\beta): B(\beta) := \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \beta_iB_i,\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \beta_i= 1,  \beta\geq 0\}$

With discrete-time ljapunov function $V_k(\alpha)= x^T_kP(\alpha)x_k$, a system $x_{k+1} = Ax_k$ is stable if:
\begin{align*}
    V_k(\alpha) &= x^T_kP(\alpha)x_k  \succ 0  \implies P(\alpha) \succ 0\\
    \Delta V_k(\alpha) &=  V_{k+1}(\alpha) - V_{k}(\alpha)  \prec 0\\
    &= x^T_{k+1}P(\alpha)x_{k+1} -  x^T_kP(\alpha)x_k = (A(\alpha)x_k)^TP(\alpha)(A(\alpha)x_k) -  x^T_kP(\alpha)x_k\\
    &= x^T_kA^T(\alpha)P(\alpha)A(\alpha)x_k - x^T_kP(\alpha)x_k\\
    &= x^T_k((A^T(\alpha)P(\alpha)A(\alpha) - P(\alpha))x_k \prec 0 \implies (A^T(\alpha)P(\alpha)A(\alpha) - P(\alpha)) \prec 0
\end{align*}
When using the Q Schur compliment and the state controller:
\begin{align*}
    u_k &= Kx_k\\
    x_{k+1} &= A(\alpha)x_k + B(\beta)u_k = A(\alpha)x_k + B(\beta)Kx_k \\
    &= \underbrace{(A(\alpha) +  B(\beta)K)}_{=A(\alpha,\beta)}x_k = A(\alpha,\beta)x_k
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \underbrace{P(\alpha,\beta)}_{R} - \underbrace{A^T(\alpha,\beta)P(\alpha,\beta)}_{S^T}\underbrace{P(\alpha,\beta)^{-1}}_{Q^{-1}}\underbrace{P(\alpha,\beta)A(\alpha,\beta)}_{S}  &\succ 0 \iff \begin{bmatrix}
P(\alpha,\beta) & P(\alpha,\beta)A(\alpha,\beta) \\
A^T(\alpha,\beta)P(\alpha,\beta) & P(\alpha,\beta) 
\end{bmatrix} \succ 0
\end{align*}
The paper says:

Theorem 1.
The following conditions are equivalent:

1. There exists a symmetric matrix $P \succ 0$ such
   that: $APA − P \prec  0$.
2. There exist a symmetric matrix $P$ and a matrix
   $G$ such that:
   $\begin{bmatrix}
   P & PA \\
   A^TP & P
   \end{bmatrix} \succ 0$

I am trying to understand the proof of the paper with:

$$T\begin{bmatrix}
P & A^TG^T \\
GA& G + G^T- P 
\end{bmatrix}T^T = P-A'PA \succ0$$

with $T =  \begin{bmatrix}
I & -A^T \end{bmatrix}$ and I am trying to do it step by step, yet I am always ending with

$$T\begin{bmatrix}
P & A^TG^T \\
GA& G + G^T - P 
\end{bmatrix}T^T =P-A^TGA-A^T(G-P)A^T$$

I am not sure if I understand the proof correctly or if I am only making a calculation error.

Comment: On which ground this question should be closed ?

Comment: 1) Please give some context : in particular why are you interested in this issue ? 2) It is better to write $A^T$ instead of $A'$ for the transpose of $A$. 3) I have added some pertinent tags (positive-definiteness, Schur complement) to your question.

Comment: The inequality certainly fails in some instances, e.g. when both $A$ and $G$ are zero or sufficiently small.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank your responds, I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You have made a mistake. In general $\begin{bmatrix}I&-A^T\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X&Y\\ Z&W\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I\\-A\end{bmatrix}=X-YA-A^TZ+A^TWA$. So, in your case, you should get $P-(A^TG)A-A^T(GA)+A^T(G+G^T-P)A=P-A^TPA$.

Comment: The cited paper can be found here: http://control.disp.uniroma2.it/zack/ftp/users/DeSimone/dilated1.pdf

Comment: Since there are no answers yet, there is no need to append an `Edit` section. Just refine the whole question. Break it into sections and choose a more descriptive title.